On the coefficients of Faber polynomials
Let $f$ be a function holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $\infty$ and assume that its Laurent expansion can be written as
$$f(z)=z+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^{-n}$$.
The $n-$th Faber polynomial $P_n$ is defined as that polynomial of degree $n$ such that
$$P_n(f(z))=z^m+\sum_{m=0}^\infty c_{n,m}z^{-m}.$$
It's a well known result due to Schur that the coefficients $c_n$ can be expressed as polynomial functions of $a_{n,m}$ (where $a_{n,m}$ are the coefficient of the Laurent expansion of $f(z)^m$, i.e. $f(z)^m=z^m+\sum a_{n,m}z^{-m}$). The problem I am interested in, however, is that of estimating the coefficients of $P_n$ directly (call tham $d_{n,m}$). It seems to me  that one should be able to find a matricial equation involving $a_{n,m}$ and $d_{n,m}$ thus allowing one to obtain a result similar to that of Schur, but I can't seem to be able to find such an expression (or at least, a version of it that is manageable). Any reference or observation would be most welcome.
